# How to know how many OR conditions are satisfied?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

How can i know that which of my result has satisfied how many number of conditions/

```
SELECT 
    [TITLE] 
FROM 
    [M_TIPS] 
WHERE 
    [TITLE] LIKE '%VALUE%' OR 
    [TITLE] LIKE '%SQL%';
```

How to know that which of the result has satisfied only 1 OR condition and which of the result has satisfied both conditions. The number of conditions are not static, it can increase.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: You could check each result after the query with which ever programming language you are using to see if it matches one or more conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add that to the result:

```
SELECT 
    [TITLE] 
    case [TITLE] LIKE '%VALUE%' WHEN true then 1 else 0 end as CONTAINS_VALUE
    case [TITLE] LIKE '%SQL%' WHEN true then 1 else 0 end as CONTAINS_SQL
FROM 
    [M_TIPS] 
WHERE 
    [TITLE] LIKE '%VALUE%' OR 
    [TITLE] LIKE '%SQL%';
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion But this will be helpful only for less number of where conditions, as the where condition is not static and if it will increase then it will not be helpful (means i have to right that many case statements).

Any solution to that?

Comment: If you have dynamic code to add conditions to the WHERE part, then you can use the same code to add columns to the SELECT part.

Answer (score 1):

Short circuiting in a WHERE clause *may prevent any match count exceeding 1 if you use OR.

How about storing your match list in a table variable then counting matches;

```
DECLARE @MATCH TABLE (SCORE INT, TOKEN VARCHAR(16))
INSERT @MATCH 
      SELECT 1, 'VALUE'
UNION SELECT 1, 'SQL'
UNION SELECT 1, 'CAKE'

SELECT 
    [TITLE], SUM(M.SCORE)
FROM 
    [M_TIPS] T INNER JOIN @MATCH M ON T.[TITLE] LIKE '%' + M.TOKEN + '%'
GROUP BY T.[TITLE]

==
sql             1
value           1
xx sql value xx 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a programming language to dynamically generate the queries with the conditions generated as required, then I suggest generating the query like so:

```
SELECT [TITLE], SUM([CONDITION_COUNT]) FROM
(SELECT [TITLE], 1 [CONDITION_COUNT] FROM [M_TIPS] 
    WHERE [TITLE] LIKE ConditionString1 UNION ALL
SELECT [TITLE], 1 [CONDITION_COUNT] FROM [M_TIPS] 
    WHERE [TITLE] LIKE ConditionString2 UNION ALL
...
SELECT [TITLE], 1 [CONDITION_COUNT] FROM [M_TIPS] 
    WHERE [TITLE] LIKE ConditionStringN) SQ
GROUP BY [TITLE]
```